# Remote Desktop Gateway adding an external hostname with powershell to a rd-gateway managed network resource group gives access denied

Tags: powershell, rds, windows-server-2016

I want to create an Remote Access Gateway Network Resource group through powershell on a RDS gateway role. The role has been installed like this:

```
Install-Windowsfeature RDS-Gateway
```

And the I try to add the external hostname to a new network resource group:

```
Import-Module RemoteDesktopServices
New-Item -Path "RDS:\GatewayServer\GatewayManagedComputerGroups" -Name "RDSInfra" -Computers "fqdn" -Description "RDS Infrastructure" -ItemType "String"
```

When I input the fqdn of a computer that is valid for the current domain, this works fine. When I put in the cname record, which is different from the domain the infrastructure is in, I get an access denied error. When I use the RD Gateway manager and create a group from there, I can add any fqdn I like and it works fine.

Can anyone reproduce this? Or even better, solve this?

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with the domain membership, but with a typo in the fqdn. The host you add does need to be resolvable before adding it to a network group.